# GWT DMP Plugin has crashed

Tags: java, gwt

In a same project and same Chrome browser I don't get this

`GWT DMP Plugin has crashed` on Linux which I get on a Windows machine a lot, when running a Maven based GWT application.

What are the primary reasons that DMP plugin will crash? And how to prevent it.

Comment: @Charmin Your link points to the same page.

Comment: Yes right. I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

[GWT and Windows 8. GWT DMP Plugin has crashed possible fix](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/09/23/GWT-and-Windows-8-GWT-DMP-Plugin-has-crashed-possible-fix.aspx)